# how to get which session is from which browser in php when cookie is disabled in browser?

Tags: php, session, cookies

Suppose i have two systems in same network,and cookie is disabled in both system browser. Now i am trying to Login to online server. Here if i am saving session using session id on server-side How will it differentiate that which user has logged-in in which browser?

if i am having `<form>` on all the pages i can pass session id as hidden field. But it's not necessary to have a `<form>` in all the pages, so how to change the url in this case.

If i am using get it can be dangerous, any one can get the user details by tracing the url.

So how will it work?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php -- append the `SID` constant to your URLs.  You may also be able to enable `session.use_trans_sid` in php.ini

Answer (score 2):

enable the `session.use_trans_sid` and disable `session.use_only_cookies`. Make sure to understand how `session.use_trans_sid` works before you use it.